# How to redirect flex buffer to my buffer

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

After days of fagging I am still unable to find how can I declare my buffer.
[how to pass tkinter text to flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168245/how-to-pass-tkinter-text-to-flex)

What is the correct way to redirect flex buffer to my buffer?
The steps I want to do:
1 - No conditions, no return to original buffer, just permanently redirect buffer from a graphic frontend by calling a function.
2 - Copy text from graphic frontend to my buffer (or even better to direct fely buffer to the frontend buffer)
3 - call yyparse
4 - repeat steps 2 and 3

Perhaps it is enough to declare a simple public function like this:

```
void setmybuffer(char *ptr)
{
yy_scan_string (char *ptr);
.... // my other stuff to set
}
```

Afterward I suppose I call it before any flex operation. But when I try to put this declaration into any part of my *.l file I get error

```
lex.yy.c: In function ‘setmybuffer’:
lex.yy.c:2206:18: error: conflicting types for ‘yy_scan_string’
  YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_string (char *ptr);
```

What's wrong and what's the way?

Answer (score 1):

```
yyscan_string(char *ptr);
```

is a declaration, so the compiler complains that the function is already declared and with a different return type.

You wanted to call the function:

```
yyscan_string(ptr);
```

So you might do something like this:

```
// This defines the function setmybuffer, which has no return value ("void")
// and a single parameter which is a pointer to a character string ("char *")
void setmybuffer(char *ptr)
{
  // This **calls** the function yy_scan_string, passing it the same pointer 
  // to a character string.
  yy_scan_string (ptr);
  .... // my other stuff to set
}
```

Note that you're required to free the `YY_BUFFER_STATE` when you're finished with it. Usually you can simply call:

```
yy_delete_buffer(YY_CURRENT_BUFFER);
```

when you are finished with the input (eg. in your `<<EOF>>` rule). For more complicated use cases, you might need to save the value returned by `yyscan_string`.

Comment: That's the thing what makes me crazy. If I write<br/>
    void setmybuffer(*ptr)<br/>
     {<br/>
     yy_scan_string(*ptr);<br/>
     }<br/>
Then the message is:<br/>
    abs.l:142:18: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘*’ token<br/>
      {<br/>
                      ^<br/>

Comment: @user2469202: you're not going to be able to accomplish this without knowing at least a little bit about how to write a C function, I'm afraid. I edited my answer to be a bit more explicit, but you should really spend a few minutes reading an introduction to C, such as http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Little_C_Primer -- which introduces function call and function definition syntaxes very early (ignore the parts which talk about the history of C. It's irrelevant.)